# Target directory not found in Docker container

Tags: docker, docusaurus

I came across such a problem. I'm locally building my docusaurus site via Docker container.

From inside a docusaurus directory I run such a command:

```
docker run -it --rm --name doc-lab --mount type=bind,source=D:\work\some_path,target=/target_path -p 3000:3000 doc-lab
```

And then when container is up, I run inside container terminal command:

```
npm --prefix=/target_path run build
```

And I get the following:

```
docusaurus: not found
```

Although there is such a directory:

```
# cd /
# ls 
bin  boot  dev  target_path  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
# npm --prefix=/target_path run build

> target_path@0.0.1 build
> docusaurus build

sh: 1: docusaurus: not found
```

What went wrong?

Successfully running a command. Site opens at localhost.

Comment: Apparently `build` script is trying to run `docusaurus build` command. What is the WORKDIR in the Dockerfile? Is there a `docusaurus` script in that dir?

Comment: Here is what in the Dockerfile:

`FROM node:16

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]`


Then I "ls" in that dir:
`# ls
Dockerfile  README.md  babel.config.js  docs  docusaurus.config.js  node_modules  package-lock.json  package.json  sidebars.js  src  static`

Comment: So the application is deployed to `/usr/src/app` directory. Could you please check what is specified for `build` script in `package.json` file? Also please try running `npm run build` from `/usr/src/app` directory and check if it works.

Comment: First for `build` I have following: `"build": "docusaurus build"`. Second, yes, I have tried to run `npm run build` but got the following: `[WARNING] Something is already running on port 3000.

Would you like to run the app on another port instead?`.

Comment: That's because you have `npm run start` specified as `CMD` in Dockerfile. So once the container is started this command will be executed and probably start listening on port 3000. Do you really need to run `npm run build` ?

Comment: Well, I guess yes. That's the scheme working on my collegue's PC, I transfered it to me but it broke =) The plan is to generate docs then to eatch them. That is the first step.

Answer (score 0):

Usually `npm run start` is used to run a development version and `npm run build` is used to prepare the files to be deployed to production environment. So in your case I think `npm run build` should be run either with a `RUN` directive in Dockerfile or even on your computer, before building the Docker image, and then the results can be copied to the target directory. And the `CMD` command in Dockerfile will then contain the command to run the production server. You can check the `scripts` section of `packages.json` file to see the actual commands behind `npm run start` and `npm run build`

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was not so simple. Just because I didn't create docker image by myself, but downloaded it I needed to run

```
npm install
```

And that was the answer.